# Certbot (letsencrypt) Could not open file sites-enabled/default

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm using an Amazon EC3 with 2 vhosts now, they both have valid certificates.

Now I want to add a third virtual host, I added the nginx config file but when I try to run the following command

**it's looking for the "default" nginx config file.** but in my case it's named "web"

```
certbot --nginx -d mysite.be www.mysite.be
```

Can I add a command so that certbot looks in my web file for the valid config instead of the default one?

Comment: Does the site work? i.e. did you do a nginx reload and can hit the site?

Comment: have you managed to get this to work ? @Miguel

Comment: @Fanckush I don't remember, it's been a long time sorry, Did you try the answer to this question?

Comment: I fixed shortly after posting the comment. I did not have the "default" config file anymore so the alias was broken. all I did. was delete the alias and certbot was able to find my other config properly

Answer (score 3):

You could make an alias.
`ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_file_name /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`